# Change working directory of msbuild.exe

Tags: msbuild

I am executing MSBuild from a batch file.  The MSBuild script is in a different directory than the directory I want MSBuild to consider the working directory when running the script.  When invoking MSBuild.exe, how do I change its working directory?

**Edit: More details**
Let's say I have an MSBuild script located on some other server.  I want to run a command thusly:

```
msbuild.exe \\my_server\c$\My\Path\To\Scripts\TestScript.msbuild
```

I run that command with my command prompt at c:\temp.  Let's say my TestScript.msbuild has a  task to create a file.  The file has no path just a filename.  I would expect that the file gets created inside c:\temp.  But it doesn't it gets created next to the msbuild file that is sitting on the server.  This is the behavior I want to change.

**Edit #2**
Here is the script I'm using in my test:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">   
    <ItemGroup>
        <Files Include="HelloWorld.txt" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="TouchFiles">
        <Touch Files="@(Files)" AlwaysCreate="True" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

I am going into a command shell CDing into c:\temp and then executing the script.  With or without the /p:OutDir switch that @Nick Nieslanik mentions, the HelloWorld.txt file appears in the folder where the *.msbuild file is and not c:\temp.

Comment: i'm not sure I understand your question.  If I have a cmd file in directory A and call it from directory B, then echo out %cd% it will show directory B as the current directory.  So unless you are changing the directory in the script, it should already consider the current dir as the working directory.  Can you clarify?

Comment: I agree with the behavior you describe.  However, MSBuild doesn't seem to do that.  It seems to take the location of the *.build file as the working directory.  I will edit my question to describe more specifics on my setup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@jkohlhepp - I see now.  You are doing the opposite of what I described in my comment to some degree.  
 
MSBuild common targets use the MSBuildProjectDirectory to determine the output folder unless you override that.  So in your case, you could run

```
msbuild.exe \\my_server\c$\My\Pat\To\Scripts\TestScript.msbuild /p:OutDir=c:\temp
```

to force the output to be dropped in that location.

EDIT: 
Given the project file above, you'd need to edit it to do something like the following for this to work:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutDir Condition=" '$(OutDir)' == '' ">bin\debug\</OutDir>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>  
    <!-- Without prefacing files with paths, they are assumed relative to the proj file -->
    <FilesToCreate Include="$(OutDir)HelloWorld.txt" />  
  </ItemGroup>  
  <Target Name="TouchFiles">  
     <Touch Files="@(FilesToCreate)" AlwaysCreate="True" />  
  </Target>  
</Project>
```

Comment: Hrmmm....that didn't seem to work for me.  In my example script which I built for this question, I have a <touch/> task that specifies a file name only, with no directory.  Even when I specify the /p:Outdir=c:\temp the touched file still ends up next to the msbuild script file.

Comment: Yes I can.  Added the full script to the question.

Comment: So!  i see what you mean now.  Without prefacing each file with some MSBuild property or copying them from the source project dir to some target location like $(OutDir), you are out of luck...  I will attempt to edit my answer and illustrate what I mean

Comment: So MSBuild just says "my working directory is where the build file is" and gives you no option to change that?  Sigh...

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Nick Nieslanik.  This is basically what I ended up doing, but I feel like I'm using my own variable to essentially keep track of "working directory", which MSBuild should be able to manage correctly on its own.  Oh well.  At least I wasn't missing something.

Comment: Well one more thing to note is that you can leverage environment variables in MSBuild Project files using the same $() syntax (i.e. $(TEMP) ... )

Comment: Perhaps `/p:OutDir="%CD%"`? Bother, why does msbuild change its working directory in the first place? `make -f path/to/Makefile` does what one would expect by not changing the working directory… `make -C` exists if you want the CWD to change!

Comment: @binki It's conceivable that it has something to do with MSBuild being more of a "project definition format", rather than a scripting language. As such the primary use would be to have a project file in a folder that deals with how to "build" the things in that folder and thus it's usually handy if relative paths extend from that folder - and unlike make you don't have to know or remember if you should use -f or -C when running some particular Makefile. Each tool has it's own pros and cons of course. In current versions, the msbuild file can reference $(MSBuildStartupDirectory) if it wants to.

Answer (score 28):

I ran across this while looking for a solution to my problem.  Here's my solution (build script):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Target Name="Default">
    <Exec Command="build.bat" WorkingDirectory="..\[your dir]\" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

I believe that's more what you were originally looking for?

My problem was that my batch file called another that it expected to be in the same directory, but since my ms build script was being run elsewhere, the batch file failed to find the second batch file.

Comment: The `WorkingDirectory` attribute was what I was looking for. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

In current versions of MSBuild the well-known property `MSBuildStartupDirectory` can be used in the msbuild file to retrieve the absolute path of the folder where MSBuild is called.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-reserved-and-well-known-properties?view=vs-2019

This option perhaps did not exist in msbuild around the time when the question was asked. I didn't want to spend too much time investigating it.