# Dotless using different folder

Tags: asp.net, dotless

I have DotLess 1.4.1 installed (Asp.Net 4.0).

My less directory structure is:

```
/assets/styles/*.less
```

I'm now looking at bootstrap and although I'll probably change the default directory structure, bootstrap will be inside its own folder. At the moment it is located:

```
/content/bootstrap/*.less
```

I've tried

```
@import "grid.less"
@import "/content/bootstrap/grid.less"
@import "../../content/bootstrap/grid.less
@import "./../../content/bootstrap/grid.less
```

Amongst many other variations.

I have a build event like this:

```
“$(SolutionDir)packages\dotless.1.4.1.0\tool\dotless.Compiler.exe” "$(ProjectDir)assets\styles\main.less” “$(ProjectDir)assets\styles\main.css”
```

Anyone experienced this kind of issue or have an idea as to how it can be solved?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that [dotless uses the current directory to look for imports](https://github.com/dotless/dotless/issues/270) even when the initial file is not in the current directory. If you're comfortable working with MSBuild files, you can [switch the working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7649414/change-working-directory-of-msbuild-exe) for the exe call.